# Error 500 when I turn on URL rewriting in back end

Tags: url, non-sef-url

I have rename htaccess.txt and changed it to .htaccess.

When I visit the site everything is fine (I think).  When I turn on rewrite URLs in the back end I get error 500. https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_check_if_mod_rewrite_is_enabled_on_your_server and it works fine, so rewriting works on the server.

Can anyone else think of the issue?

Comment: If someone else visits.  This could potentially be a rule in the .htaccess file even though it only appears to occur on rewrite URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always worth **checking the standard Joomla! .htaccess file** vs the one you are using in case someone or some component/plugin has added extra rules that cause a clash.

Answer (score 0):

Have you definitely got MOD_REWRITE enabled on the server?

Regards
D

Comment: Yes, I have tested this using the instructions in the link I posted in the question